# "Pick locator" tool not working on dotnet Playwright project

Tags: playwright-dotnet

I've started a dotnet (C#) project using Playwright and I noticed after installing every thing on VS Code, when I click "Pick locator" tool from Playwright I get the following error:
"No Playwright tests found."

But I do have a test using NUnit (UnitTest1.cs). Is there a way I can launch the "Pick locator" tool on a dotnet project, because I know this works when using Javascript?

The workaround I found is to launch "CodeGen" from Playwright on CL.

Comment: apart from codegen there is no option to open the pick locator window